# Login issue after publishing .Net Core 3.1 web app to IIS

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a .Net Core 3.1 MVC application that is using induvial user accounts as authentication. I deployed the site to IIS, which works. However when I tried to log in with an account I know that works, the login does not succeed, and I am directed back the default route of the application. No error messages or log entries that I can find. The application pool is set up for non managed code, and is running under an account that has dbo rights to the database. Any thoughts as to what the issue might be?

http://localhost:44360/     running on server on Visual Studio 2022
http://localhost:2710/     running on server on IIS
http:// domain . com          not working

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult for everyone to help you without error messages. Have you tried swapping to a development environment to see the details of the error?

Locate the Web.config file and adjust it to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable as follows:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProjectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

This method worked for me to find the error, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This field already exists in the web.config file.
It gives a warning when the user is wrong, but when we enter the correct user information, it does not create cookies or sessions and does not fall into any errors.